# java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\Mr_sk\Desktop\account.mdb

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess

I created my java project using Ms Access Database and after clean and build the project i get the .jar file of my java application. It's work good but Now i am trying to create .exe file of java application using my .jar file. but after creating .exe file its give me the error like ***java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\Mr_sk\Desktop\account.mdb***.
I am using ucanaccess library for database connectivity.

I will be thankful if you give me solution for my project

Comment: So when you built the exe, you forgot to include the JDBC driver jar file. Since you didn't show *anything* about how you built the exe, we can't help with that.

Comment: I used launch4j for creating .exe file. I will update my post later with code also i added all the library and jdbc jar file also

Answer (score 1):

Guys I find the solution.
I added this line 
**Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");**
and error is gone.